# How to get real time zone offset taking into account daylight saving?

Tags: java, timezone, timezone-offset

I am in +3 timezone now.
Now UTC time is 16:30 and at my place it is 19:30

I found an issue that for time zone `America/Los_Angeles`

which is theoretically -8 (rawOffset) I get unexpected time.
I expected that if in my place 20:00, then at ths timezoe time should be 11 hours less(8+3) but in real life it is 10 hours less than in my place because of daylight saving.

So how can I get -7 offset if I have `America/Los_Angeles` zoneId in my code ?

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles").getRawOffset()/(3600*1000)
```

returns -8 but now it differs from UTC for 7 hours

[image]

Comment: @Eugene added a bit more details.

Comment: sorry, still I can't understand. read your first phrase alone, it makes no sense

Comment: In order to know if DST is in effect, we need to know the date for that time. Without the date part, the system cannot determine of DST is active. In short, without date, what you're asking cannot be done.

Comment: @Andreas lets imagine that we have date

Comment: Then call [`getOffset(long date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getOffset-long-) instead of `getRawOffset()`

Comment: `TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles").getOffset(new Date().getTime())/(3600 *1000)` it returns -7 - cool!

Comment: *FYI:* It is common for time zone offsets to not be full hours, e.g. India's offset is 5 hours 30 minutes.

Comment: @Andreas yes - good catch and in Austalia the same

Comment: If you want to know if DST is in effect *right now*, use `getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis())`. No need to create a `Date` object.

Comment: @Eugene it was attempt to show you my timezone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to know the time zone offset that is correctly adjusted for DST, don't use [`getRawOffset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getRawOffset--), since that is specifically the offset without DST. As the documentation says it:

> Returns the amount of time in milliseconds to add to UTC to get standard time in this time zone. Because this value is **not affected by daylight saving time**, it is called *raw offset*.

To know if DST is in effect, the system needs to know the *date*, not just the *time*. If you know the full date/time, then you can get the offset by calling e.g. [`getOffset(long date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getOffset-long-).

To get the time zone offset in effect *right now*, call:

```java
int offset = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")
                     .getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis());
int minutes = offset / 60000;
```

With the Java 8 Time API, the equivalent code is:

```java
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")
                          .getRules().getOffset(Instant.now());
int minutes = offset.getTotalSeconds() / 60;
```

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The [answer by Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67940870/10819573) is correct. This answer provides the solution using the modern Date-Time API.

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>, released in March 2014 as part of Java SE 8 standard library.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneOffset offset = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")).getOffset();
        System.out.println(offset);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
-07:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/2Me2eq)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Actually, the Java 8 way of my answer is: `ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles").getRules().getOffset(Instant.now())`